# Use 2 or more OPTARG in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to make a "professional" script, I use $1,$2... but now I am learning about getopts.

This is my little script:

```
function name(){
         echo "My name is $1"
}
function last_name(){
         echo "My last name is $1"
}
function name_complete(){
}
while getopts ":n:p:" option;do
      case $option in
           n)
              n=$OPTARG
              name $n
           ;;
           p)
              p=$OPTARG
              last_name $p
           ;;
      esac
done
```

I would like to know how I could use `name_complete` with `-n` and `-p`

For expample:

`./script.sh -n John -p Doe`

My name is John Doe

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Run your functions **after** your `while getopts` - loop:

```bsh
function name_complete(){
    printf 'My name is %s %s\n' "$1" "$2"
}

while getopts ":n:p:" option; do
      case "$option" in
           n)
              n=$OPTARG
              ;;
           p)
              p=$OPTARG
              ;;
      esac
done

name_complete "$n" "$p"
```

Note, you should always quote your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a start:

```
while getopts ":n:p:" option;do
      case $option in
           n)
              n=$OPTARG
           ;;
           p)
              p=$OPTARG
           ;;
      esac
done

if [ -n "$n" -a -n "$p" ] ; then
  name_complete "$n" "$p"
elif [ -n "$n" ] ; then
  name "$n"
elif [ -n "$p" ] ; then
  last_name "$p"
else
  echo At least one option is needed
fi
```